# Table with big XML data is terribly slow to query from application

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Well I have a simple table which contains an Id (Primary Key, Identity and Index), Revision, Timestamp and the XML data. We currently store ~700 rows of data with approx. 2-15 MB of XML data each.

Now in my application I first query to find out the latest revision. When I have the Id with the most up-to-date entry, I query the data using the Id as selector.

When I execute this statement in SSMS: `SELECT Data FROM XmlDb where Id = 1733` it takes less than one second to return the data. When I do the same in my .Net application it takes around 76 seconds to do so.

Can anyone explain where this comes from and how I can speed it up? It seems to become slower the more rows the table contains. But why is SSMS so much faster querying it?

I tried it with various approaches, used Entity Framework Core and then manual queries. No matter what it keeps being slow.

Comment: From the time difference between ssms  and application my first guess would be that  the .Net code does is get the entire table and then filter out the row. If so, you need to rewrite the .Net part. Try running a trace on on your database to check what is actually asked for (SQL Server Profiler)

Comment: I get a *SQL:BatchCompleted* for `SELECT Id, Revision FROM XmlDb ORDER BY Timestamp DESC` and after that a seemingly slow *RPC:Completed* `exec sp_executesql N'SELECT Data FROM XmlDb WHERE Id = @Id',N'@Id int',@Id=2305` which still does only take 39382ms in the profiler but ~58s to actually end up in the program. **EDIT**: Yes, SSMS does actually execute it as regular SQL statement, whereas my SELECT statement gets executed via `EXEC` for some reason.

Comment: Furthermore: I changed it from using `SqlParameter` and inserted the Id directly into the statement. Now it does not execute dynamically anymore - but still takes exactly the same time ~36552ms. It's the very same statement as in SSMS.

Comment: Does SSMS bring back the entire XML data block, or does it truncate it?

Comment: Is SSMS running on the same PC that your .NET application is running on? Just wondering if you may be running SSMS directly on the SQL server, while the .NET app could be running on a remote PC.

Comment: @JMabee I explicitly set the limit for XML data high enough so it retrieves all. Usually it would return with an error message.
Wiz: yes, it runs on the same machine. That's why I'm so confused...